# Perl Backup Script Advice and Examples Please

Tags: perl, backup

I am trying to create some backup scripts written in perl.

I am just after some examples best practises etc..

Problem:

Backup files and directories from various locations on a system, is it better to move to a temp location then tar and zip them? or just do it from where they are?

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out http://backup2l.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are approximately six million backup scripts floating around the web.

[Here is one I wrote about eight years ago, it still works for me](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=272952).